# Method with one parameter to draw a cross

Tags: java, loops, methods

so I need to use a method with one parameter to draw a cross whose size is dictated by that parameter. So drawCross(5) would be:

```
  *
  *
*****
  *
  *
```

I can't seem to get it to work. My code will ask for a number, but then nothing. I'm sure it's probably just me being stupid, but I can't for the life of me figure out what it is. Here's what I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab9E1CrossTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Number: ");
        int n = kbd.nextInt();

        drawCross(n);

        kbd.close();
    }

    public static void drawCross(int n) {
        int lineCounter = 1, charCounter = 1;
        if (n % 2 == 1) {
            while (lineCounter <= n) {
                if (lineCounter == ((n / 2) + 1)) { // determines if middle line
                                                    // by dividing n by two then
                                                    // adding 1 (ex. middle of 5
                                                    // is 3, so 5/2=2, +1=3)
                    charCounter = 1;
                    while (charCounter <= n) { // prints out n number of stars
                                               // on one line
                        System.out.print("*");
                        charCounter++;
                    }
                } else {
                    charCounter = 1;
                    while (lineCounter != ((n / 2) + 1)) {
                        if (charCounter == ((n / 2) + 1)) { // if middle char of
                                                            // line
                            System.out.print("*");
                        } else {
                            System.out.print(" ");
                        }
                        charCounter++;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(); // makes sure prints on new line
                lineCounter++;
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: Number is even.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your program? What values have you tried?

Comment: Just tried debugging, with no luck. I've tried a whack of values. It'll ask me for a number, flicker one * on the screen then just keep running but printing nothing.

Comment: Do you know what I mean by debugging? Putting a breakpoint and stepping through the lines of your code to see where it gets you. That _should_ really help you see where the problem is.

Comment: caught it. Had an infinite loop at line 30, while(lineCounter != ((n/2)+1)). changed it to an if and added while(charCounter<=n) below it and it works fine

Comment: Yeah I just found it as well, actually debugged your code :)

Answer (score 0):

I would start by validating the user input at the time you receive it (e.g. make sure it's even before you call `drawCross`).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Number: ");
    if (kbd.hasNextInt()) {
        int n = kbd.nextInt();
        if (n % 2 != 0) {
            drawCross(n);
        } else {
            System.out.printf("Please enter an odd #, %d is even%n", n);
        }
    }
}
```

Next, I suggest you create a utility method to repeat a specific character `n` times. You can then draw your cross with the repeating `String`(s)

```
private static String repeat(char ch, int n) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sb.append(ch);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Something like,

```
public static void drawCross(int n) {
    int mid = (n / 2);
    String spaces = repeat(' ', mid);
    for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
        System.out.println(spaces + '*');
    }
    System.out.println(repeat('*', n));
    for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
        System.out.println(spaces + '*');
    }
}
```